# Java Arrays and Objects for calls in a queue

Tags: java, arrays

so am new to Java and want to understand how object arrays work . For a scenarios like this , calls are placed in a queue[0-9] and am trying to model these cases:

An instance variable which is an array of Calls to form the queue. 
A second instance variable, an int which will hold the number of calls currently in the queue. 
A constructor which takes the required size of the queue as its parameter and initialises the array to be of that size. 
A method void add(Call call) which adds a call to the queue. 
A method to get the number of calls currently in the queue. 
A method boolean isEmpty() to check whether the queue is currently empty. 
A new method to check whether the queue is full.

```
public class TrafficQueue {

    private Call[] callArray;
    private int numberOfCalls;

    private int  addIndex=-1;

    public TrafficQueue (int size)
    {
        callArray = new Call[size];
    }



    public void add(Call call)
    {
        addIndex++;
        callArray[addIndex] = call;

    }

    //can't return an int here just true/false.
    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
     boolean isEmpty= false;

     for (int i = 0; i < callArray.length; i++){

         if(callArray[i] != null)
         {
             isEmpty = true;
         }
     }
     return isEmpty;

    }

    public int NumberofCalls()
    {
     return addIndex + 1;
    }


    //We can't simply check the count, we have to make sure that at each index there is a value.
    //Count just tells us the size of the array. 
    public boolean isfull()
    {
        int notNull = -1;

        for(int i=0; i<callArray.length; i++){

            if(callArray[i] != null)
            {
                notNull++;
            }
        }

        if(notNull == callArray.length -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

How can I model these scenarios?? Is this approach correct? is there a better way?

Comment: as you only add to the end of the Q, you can simplify isfull() and isEmpty() methods to only check the last or the first element of the array. Also, private int numberOfCalls is not used

Comment: ok how do i go about this?

Comment: the Q is empty if callArray[0] == null. It is full if callArray[callArray.length-1] != null

Comment: ok still dont get how this will fit in the current code premek.

Comment: Is it your home work from the university? If you want to learn something try understand your requirements and as good example you can look at ArrayList implementation in standard JDK.

Comment: ArrayList can make it easy as i have learnt wanted to use basic arrays for now...

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is correct. The isFull() and isEmpty() is a little bit oversized. It could simply check the value of addIndex. isFull() { return addIndex >= (callArray.length -1); } and isEmpty() {return addIndex = -1;}

Another improvement would be to check in add() if there is still space in the queue to prevent an IndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
if ( isFull() ) doSomething();
```

The doSomething can either throw your own Exception or just quit the add() method without doing anything.